# No system image named 'airport.express' was found

Tags: swiftui, sf-symbols

I'm using SwiftUI SF Symbols, all works well on iOS 14, but not iOS 13, the error is like:

```
[SwiftUI] No system image named 'doc.badge.gearshape' was found
[SwiftUI] No system image named 'airport.express' was found
[SwiftUI] No system image named 'rectangle.badge.plus' was found
```

The usage is very simple:

```
Image(systemName: "doc.badge.gearshape")
```

If this is because the icons are exit on iOS 14 only then what's the proper way to solve this?
Do I have to use:

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        Image(systemName: "doc.badge.gearshape")
} else {
    Image("xxx")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. These are symbols added from iOS 14.0. [New symbols from iOS 14.0](https://noahgilmore.com/blog/sf-symbols-ios-14/)

You will have to use alternative images for iOS 13.0 as you have already mentioned in the code snippet above.